# Method Cells object of Worksheet failed

Tags: vba, excel

My code throws the following error:

> run time error -2147417748(80010108)
>   Method Cells of Object Worksheet failed

After it has traversed the counter2 loop 7 times on the 8th iteration of the outer loop it throws the error. This is strange given that the same loop on the same data is running properly in the same macro just before this piece of code:

```
Do While Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter2, 1).Value <> ""
    If (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter2, categoryPoint).Value = _
        Worksheets("Sheet5").Cells(counter, 4).Value) _
        And (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter2, subCategoryPoint).Value = _
        Worksheets("Sheet5").Cells(counter, 5).Value) Then

        Do While counter3 <> attrCount + 1
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter2, counter3).Value = "" Then gold = gold + 1
             counter3 = counter3 + 1
        Loop
        counter2 = counter2 + 1
        counter3 = 1
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the values of all of those variables at the time it errors...

Comment: counter2 = 8, categoryPoint 29, subCategoryPoint 33, counter 3, counter3 1. gold = 3. I don't think it has anything to do with the variables. Cells object is failing. The same loop runs fine with the same data. When i same same i mean exactly the same loop. With same variables changing same values. Only difference is the check in the if condition and that is not where it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind it was a silly error where the loop was infinite. Wonder why it threw a weird error. Thanks anyway!